# OpenVPN for certain IPs, eth0 for everything else

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, linux-networking, ubuntu-16.04

Summary: I'd like to connect to my VPN and have access to certain servers, but for all other traffic I'd like to use my regular networking.

I've setup an OpenVPN server on my VPS, my `server.conf` file looks like so:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4
push "route 10.132.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

I use the following `.ovpn` file to setup the VPN Connection:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <my.vpn.server.com> 1194
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>....</ca>
<cert>...</cert>
<key>...</key>
```

Finally, in the Network Manager for the VPN Connection, under IPv4 Settings I have made sure to set the "Method" to "Automatic (VPN) addresses only".

VPN connects fine, I can access all the internal servers I need (10.132.x.x), however I cannot access anything else (like google.com).  I'd like my eth0 settings to be used for everything except for the 10.132.x.x IPs which I would like routed through the VPN.

P.S. based on other articles I've tried using `no-pull` in the .ovpn file and adding in my `route` settings there but to no avail.

**EDIT 1**:

Results of running `ip a` and `traceroute` while connected to VPN:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:dc:a6:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86320sec preferred_lft 86320sec
    inet6 fe80::f3d1:6eb3:e13e:d61b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5/32 brd 10.8.0.6 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ traceroute google.com
google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

**EDIT 2**: results of `ip r`

```
$ ip r
default via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto static  metric 50 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto static  metric 50 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6  metric 50 
10.132.0.0/16 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto static  metric 50 
104.236.239.153 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `ip a` and `traceroute google.com` while connected to the VPN? The config looks fine to me.

Comment: @Lenniey updated the question with the results. NOt sure if it's worth noting or not, but the client machine is in a VPN. When I `traceroute google.com` without the VPN connected, it says:
` 1  10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2)  0.136 ms  0.092 ms  0.127 ms`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ip r` ... to see the routes. Can you resolve / ping google.com if you are not connected to the VPN? Doesn't seem like you can. And if you can't: how should you be able to use eth0 to connect to the internet or whatever?

Comment: Ooops, meant to say "the client machine is in a VM" not VPN.

Comment: @Lenniey I believe that might be VM networking playing tricks. I am able to load google.com fine from curl or a browser when not connected to the VPN even though the traceroute looks ganky. I've updated the answer with `ip r`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to get the desired effect by playing around with the client GUI (Ubuntu NetworkManager). I had to make sure the checkbox under `IPv4 Settings -> Routes` for "Use this connection only for resources on its network" was checked:

[image: "Use this connection only for resrouces on its network]

I'm not entirely sure what I would need to do in the .ovpn file in order to replicate this.

My routing table now looks like so:

```
$ sudo netstat -r -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.132.0.0      10.8.0.5        255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 tun0
104.236.239.153 10.0.2.2        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Remember that I had the `push "route 10.132.0.0 255.255.0.0"` in my `server.conf` so that explains the entry for `10.132.0.0` and thus why I can now access my servers while everything else is routed outside the VPN (i.e. the `0.0.0.0` entry)

Without this setting being checked in the GUI my routing table looked like this:

```
$ sudo netstat -r -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.132.0.0      10.8.0.5        255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 tun0
104.236.239.153 10.0.2.2        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

My guess is that first `0.0.0.0` entry (default route) was messing everything up.

Comment: So there is a ovpn option for turning **OFF** this `Use this connection only for resources on its network` behaviour and it's called `redirect-gateway def1`. That is equivalent to unchecking the checkbox. However, in the absence of this setting it is up to the client GUI to decide whether by default they want all traffic to route through the VPN. In the case of Ubuntu NetworkManager, they default to launching OpenVPN using `--redirect-gateway def1` but won't if you check that box...

Answer (score 19):

The "*Use this connection only for resources on its network*" checkbox in nm-connection-editor controls whether NetworkManager should add a default route through the VPN. If it is checked, as you did, only packets directed to the VPN subnet will go through the VPN gateway and the system will use the existing default route for other destinations.

You can change the same setting from command line using nmcli:

```
nmcli connection modify <VPN connection> ipv4.never-default yes
```

Comment: +1 Briljant! This is the right answer if you have a bug in your NetworkManager which prevents you from saving any changes to your connection configuration.

Answer (score 3):

To expound on jdmorei's answer, you need what is called a "split tunnel" VPN - you actually almost had the solution when you stated: `P.S. based on other articles I've tried using no-pull in the .ovpn file and adding in my route settings there but to no avail.`.

You will want the following in your ovpn file:

```
route-nopull # Make sure not to pull the default routes
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 # Route the /24 of 10.8.0.0 across the VPN
route 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.255 # Route the /32 (single IP) across the VPN
```

Now the key is that, since you are running windows, you ***must*** run the openvpn application as an administrator. If you do not, you will see entries in the log like:

```
Sat Nov 13 11:31:05 2010 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry
: Access denied.   [status=5 if_index=11]
The requested operation requires elevation. 
Sat Nov 13 11:31:05 2010 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: ret
urned error code 1
Sat Nov 13 11:31:05 2010 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Comment: Actually the VM (where the VPN client is) is Ubuntu 16.04. I'll give your suggestions a try, thank you!

Comment: Ah - sorry, when you said network manager, I had assumed Windows. If you could post your openvpn connection log, that would be helpful as well

Comment: Looks like I solved the mystery, but do you happen to know how to configure what I did through the .ovpn file instead of through the GUI as depicted in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

if your server is **/24** (**10.8.0.X**)

*server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0*

and route for your clients is **/16** (**10.132.X.X**)

*push "route 10.132.0.0 255.255.0.0"*

Maybe it wouldn't be a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FreshTomato here. I managed to only redirect 3 destination IPs to the VPN.

Below is the OpenVPN custom configuration:

```
allow-pull-fqdn
route-nopull
script-security 2
up /opt/openvpn-routes.sh
```

Then the script mentioned above:

```bash
root@router:/tmp/home/root# cat /opt/openvpn-routes.sh 
#!/bin/sh
ip route add 204.11.51.251/32  dev tun11 # www.linksysinfo.org
ip route add 201.54.48.99/32   dev tun11 # www12.senado.leg.br
ip route add 34.160.111.145/32 dev tun11 # ifconfig.me
```

The /opt mount point was set up following the instructions from https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-TomatoUSB-and-FreshTomato